# How to implement a selection menu on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, select, sdk

How do I implement this menu in the iPhone SDK?

[image: http://www.simplemobilereview.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/iphone-way.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to implement a [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).